# PNP transistor circuit

Tags: pnp

[image]

When switch \$S\$ is at position \$1\$:

$$V_B = R_2 \mathbin{/} (R_1 + R_2)*V_{CC} = 30 \mathbin{/} 130*-20=-4.62\mathrm{V}$$
$$R_{TH}=100*30 \mathbin{/} 100+30=23.1\mathrm{kOhm}$$
$$V_{TH}-I_ER_E-V_{BE}-I_BR_{TH}=0$$

where \$I_B= I_E \mathbin{/} \beta\$ and \$V_{BE} =0.7\mathrm{V}\$.

So,

\$I_E= V_{TH}-V_{BE}\mathbin{/} (R_E + R_{TH} \mathbin{/} \beta)\$

\$I_E= (-4.62-0.7) \mathbin{/} (500+23100 \mathbin{/} 110)\$

\$I_E=-7.49\mathrm{mA}\$

$$V_E = V_B + 0.7 = -4.62+0.7 = -3.92\mathrm{V}$$

\$V_C = -V_{CC} + I_CR_C\$

\$V_C = -20 + 7.49*2000 \mathbin{/} 1000\$

$$V_C = -5.02\mathrm{V}$$

$$V_{CE} = V_E -V_C = -5.02 - (-3.92) = -1.1\mathrm{V}$$

$$P = IV = -1.1 * -7.49 \mathbin{/} 1000 = 8.24\mathrm{mW}$$

Am I right?

Comment: The bias resistors are not connected to the base at all in the schematic. (Where is the junction dot?)

Comment: With a supply of -20V on the divider, current will flow from ground through the bias resistors, right? That would make `Vbase = -20*(100/130) = -15.4V`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. (But I should type at least 30 characters, where 3 are enough.)

Comment: i don't know how to do with it when it is in position 2. i know the two 30k ohm resistor are parallel. but how about the resistor R??

Comment: @Timoo U(r)=Ib*R and it is actually very small value that can be ignored. (Well, if R is very big it can't be ignored, but then you need to know the value of R then)

Comment: 3. The circuit of fig.Q3 shows a voltage-divider biasing scheme for a pnp transistor with β = 110. Switch S in position 1 shorts out resistor R, but when in position 2, it connects R1 in parallel with R2 and also maintains R in circuit. Find the value of R such that the power dissipated by the transistor with the switch in position 1 is half the value when the switch is in position 2

Comment: Here's the questions that it said i have to calculate the value of R.

Comment: @Timoo - according to what conditions you have to calculate the value of R??? If there is no conditions defined, then R can be random.

Comment: Find the value of R such that the power dissipated by the transistor with the switch in position 1 is half the value when the switch is in position 2 –